# Why the need to use "this" (some tut)

Tags: c#

Just following some tutorial(http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Hiding_and_Showing_Forms_in_C_Sharp)
which says:

*As mentioned in the previous section, in order to remove a form both from the display, and from memory, it is necessary to Close rather than Hide it. In Visual Studio double click, once again, the button in subForm to view the Click event procedure. Once again, because the button is in the form we are closing we need to use this instead of subForm when calling the Close() method:*

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
            this.Close();
  }
```

I still don't get reason why to use `this.Close()` here, as opposed to just `Close()`?

(smth similar is being said about `Hide()` method, one section above).

Comment: The only real reason is for defined scope. It doesn't particular matter for most circumstances. For example, if you try to display a messagebox whilst making another form have focus, it may not appear above the form you were hoping it to. having "this" as a parent would prevent this

Comment: ps. mysterious downvotes :)

Comment: @Sayse But this is not exactly the scenario he's asking for. There *is* a difference between `ShowDialog();` and `ShowDialog(this);`, but there's really no difference between `this.Close();` and `Close();`.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar - I agree (assuming Marc Gravells example isn't in use). I was more answering the title of the question with my original comment

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In this case `this` can actually be omitted. `this` means simply "the current instance of the class". There are cases when `this` is necessary, for example when an instance variable has the same name as a local variable. In that case, `this` must be used to access the instance variable instead of the local one.

Example:

```
public class Test
{
    private int i;

    public Test(int i)
    {
        this.i = i; // Sets the instance variable
        i = 1; // Sets the local variable
    }
}
```

---

EDIT: Marc Gravell correctly mentions extension methods, which only function on instances. So to call some method on the current instance of a class you must use `this`, too.

Comment: I understand, that's why I thought why not use `Close()` directly. I think author is referring to smth else in the tutorial, which is a bit confusing because initially he never used `this` to access ivars. Anyway, so I assume using this is similar to when you'd use `this` in other languages (basically I think in most cases you can use ivars directly).

Comment: I like to use `this` to access inherited methods.  Particularly when using framework or 3rd party base classes.  It tells me straight away that this is a method that is not in my file or even my solution but is a method of the class.

Comment: @Ben the problem there is: it doesn't *really* tell you that; it just tells you that you added `this.` when you invoked it.

Comment: @MarcGravell yes sure, it just states the intention at the time of creation.  Further down the road built-in methods can be overriden or hidden by methods in the same file and so really this is just used as an indication.  A `Close()` method without a `this.` suggests that the file should contain a new or overriden Close() method by design, which can help debugging (step-in rather than step-over).  A `this.Close()` would indicate that the original design intention was to use the inherited method (but as you say, this is no guarantee).  This is just the way I like to do things.

Comment: @Ben This is wrong. `this` has nothing to do with whether the current "file" contains an overridden version or not. `this` just indicates that "the current instance" should be used. To call the inherited method, `this` is not even the correct way. You'd have to use `base` to do that.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar In a class that does not override or hide a method is there any difference between using `base.` and `this.`?  Sure if the base method **must** be called always then I use `base.`, but using `this.` indicates that the design consideration was to use the inherited method but allows the flexibility to override or hide in future.

Comment: @Ben The use of `this` has nothing to do with inheritance or with "flexibility to override or hide in the future". Any member can be accessed with/without `this` from the members of the class itself. It simply doesn't matter whether the member was present in a base class or will be overridden by some derived class. All that `this` says is "access the member of the current instance". `this` is actually there to allow you to pass "the current instance" to some other method (like `ShowDialog(this);`). Whether you put it before a method call (as in `this.Close();`) or not doesn't change anything.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar yes I agree that if you put `this.` before a method call or not doesn't change anything.  I was not trying to suggest that it does. I was only saying when I use it and when I do not use it and why.  It is a personal style only.  If you do not like this then that is ok, but the way I do things works very well for me and it might work for others too.

Comment: @Ben I didn't get that this is your personal style. No, I don't see the point, but if it works for you... :-)

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar Sorry that I did not communicate my comment very well.

Answer (score 4):

In most cases, that will not be necessary. Since it isn't conflicting with any local variables (because there *aren't* any local variables), the only time it would be *required* is if `Close()` is an *extension method* available to the current instance. However, some people prefer to add it for "clarity" (I'm not sure it adds any, personally).

As a minor note: here's an example of when it *would* be ambiguous due to a local:

```
Action Close = delegate { Console.WriteLine("hello"); }; // or whatever
this.Close(); // calls the instance method or extension method
Close(); // invokes the local delegate
```

Finally, there are cases where `this.Foo()` is desirable because `base.Foo()` or `otherObject.Foo()` is also used in the same method, and it is desirable to keep them obvious. For example, in a `.Equals(...)` or `.CompareTo(...)` method.

Answer (score 1):

`this` is used for the current instance field/properties/methods/constructors/events etc. Therefore just using `Close()` would help.

However in cases where you might have more than one field/object within a field, it might not invoke/use the object one. In that case you have to explicitly state `this`

An example would be

```
void someMethod(FooClass someClass) {
    this.someClass = someClass; //assigning the local someClass field to the current object's someClass field.
}
```

Comment: "`this` is used for the current object field/properties" - the last three words here are incorrect; firstly, `this` relates simply to the current instance: *everything* about the current instance (not just fields/properties); and secondly: not all instances are objects

Comment: Sorry my bad, I changed the object to instance. I know it's everything of the current instance but what else are there apart from fields, methods and constructors?

Comment: you said "field/properties". You missed out "methods", "events", "indexers", "constructors", "operators" etc; "members" is a nice catch-all ;p

Answer (score 0):

From what i understand in the tutorial, its not about the `this`, its about making clear that the current window is being closed/hidden. Besides that, `this` is for some people a matter of style, to make it even clearer that this instance is meant. It is optional. Unless you need a way to pass the current instance to a method for example, than you need `this`.